# Gerrit Application flow

Tags: git, gerrit

In order to debug some issues with Gerrit I'm trying to understand the flow of the application. [image: Gerrit App Flow]

In the picture above my assumption is that in step 1 the git repo is updated, in 2 a change is created. After which the change is replicated (4) or the push is aborted (5) (the user gets a Internal Server error). Are my assumptions true? Or are these changes more transactional? Where it either does all or nothing, including updating the Git repo? Does any of you have a link to documentation where there is more information about the internals of Gerrit?

Comment: Replication is asynchronous, i.e. the push operation doesn't wait for the replication. I suspect you'll get more useful help if you ask about the actual problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually we have two problems. 1. We see Internal Server errors when pushing to Gerrit since the connection from the connection pool is invalid, and 2. we have replication issues where master and slave a not in sync. To understand what is happening and why it is failing, understanding the application/data/process flow seems the right approach to me. My impression is that replication waits for the push to complete (the change to be created) before it is triggered. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, replication doesn't start until the ref has been updated on the master server. Replication doesn't care about _changes_ per se; it only cares about Git refs. I don't know what expectations you have on the replication, but there are no real-time guarantees.

Comment: Based on what I see replication is not triggered when the ref has been updated, but when the change transaction completes. My expectation is that it's all or nothing. So Git ref update, Gerrit change and replication are completed all together, or they are all rolled back when there is a failure (including undoing of the Git ref update). Right now we can get a ref update, but no Gerrit change update/creation and no replication. I don't mind if the replication is not real time, but it should be reliable, and at the moment it's not.